Locomotive Smooth Scroll Lagging Over Image-Heavy Infinite Scroller
Context:
I’m working on a college project where I’ve implemented smooth scrolling using Locomotive Scroll. The page has an infinite side-scrolling section that displays a lot of images and logos.
Problem:
When the smooth scroll reaches the image-heavy section, the entire page starts to lag. The infinite side scroller works fine on its own, but combined with Locomotive Scroll, the performance drops significantly, takes a while but work oki later the first time is laggy.
What can I do to prevent Locomotive Scroll from lagging when it encounters the image-heavy infinite side-scroller?
idk if i should just paste my html , css and js as they scroller info mighth be imp so i will just link my github repo where i have been uploding it
https://github.com/shindeparth/Brainery
sry its my first time so idk the correct way
idk much actully im a design studen to have intrest in codding soo im figuring it out myself. but it works fine with locomotive off ,
